# I'm getting Exception jniopencv_core.dll: Can't find dependent libraries error while trying Sikuli Java API test example

Tags: java, maven, image-processing, java-native-interface, sikuli

I want to test Sikuli Java API, to be specific http://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/wiki/SikuliWebDriver . The dependency is added using maven, i.e.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sikuli</groupId>
    <artifactId>sikuli-webdriver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
```

I'm using IntelliJ Idea 11 Community Edition on 64-bit Windows 7. 32-bit JDK 6 is used in project.

I tried to use maven dependencies out of box as it described on the project site (still remembering, that there should be some native .dll installation, which doesn't occure when we use maven depencdencies only). In runtime I've get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\javacpp26205597583997\jniopencv_core.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Then I downloaded sikuli-r930-win32, installed it to C:\SikuliX. then added SIKULI_HOME system variable, setting path to C:\SikuliX. But still get the same error message in runtime.

Please, help! Just ideas what to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was checked with http://DependencyWalker.com  that opencv_core240.dll was lost (possibly, a common Windows 7 bug). After it was downloaded from https://code.google.com/p/myrobotlab/source/browse/trunk/myrobotlab/thirdParty/repo/net.sourceforge.opencv/opencv/2.4.0/x86.64.windows/opencv_core240.dll?r=711 and placed to C:\SikuliX\libs\ together with other .dlls, the problem was solved.